# Plotting a graph row by row from a table using matlab (Instead of column)

Tags: matlab, graph, plot, axis-labels

I have a data set that looks like as below and i want to plot them into a graph. I have seen a couple of examples online for graphs , however they are plotting column by column and the data source are from different matrix file.

What i am trying to achieve is to plot multiple graphs on the same figure using the data set as below.

[image]
My final product that i am trying to achieve is the image below. Can someone be kind enough to guide or point me in the right direction ?
[image]
The C1990 stands for carbon emission yr 1990.

So far i was able to plot the following but with much changes to the data source, rearranging and performing transpose operation.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a starting point.

```
data = rand(5, 20); // random data for five countries
countries = {'Afghanistan', 'Argentina', 'Australia', 'Austria', 'Belgium'}; // cell array containing the names of the countries

H = zeros(size(countries));

hold on

H = plot(data', 'Marker', '.', 'LineWidth', 1.0, 'MarkerSize', 16);

legend(H, countries)
```

Output:

[image]

This answers the question how to plot multiple graphs (by row). To polish the plot you just have to play with different properties of the graphs and the axes.

Comment: I kept getting an error ** Error using plot
Invalid first data argument** any idea why is that so ?

`combine = table(C1990Copy, C1991, C1992, C1993, C1994, C1995, C1996, C1997, C1998, C1999, C2000, C2001, C2002, C2003, C2004, C2005, C2006, C2007, C2008, C2009, C2010,...
                'RowNames', Country);


data = combine(5, 20); 
countries = {'Afghanistan', 'Argentina', 'Australia', 'Austria', 'Belgium'}; 

H = zeros(size(countries));

hold on

H = plot('data', 'Marker', '.', 'LineWidth', 1.0, 'MarkerSize', 16);

legend(H, countries)`

Comment: Also does the 20 represent the number of column to put in ?

Comment: Please try removing the single quote before `data` but keep the single quote after it because it transposes the matrix. Yes, `20` represents the number of columns.

Comment: I see. I added the single quote as i got this **Error using  '  (line 396)
Undefined function 'ctranspose' for input arguments of type 'table'.**  It might be the format of my table. was yours a matrix or cell or table ?

Comment: Yeap. It was my table format. Apparently it doesnt accept data in tables. Matrix is fine

Comment: Also i have made a slight changes. `data = random(1:60, 1:21);` Will select rows 1 - 60 and column 1 - 21. Strangely doing it the way you suggested doesnt work for me.